# Using Bootstrap Dropdown Buttons as a Form Select Box

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

http://www.benknowscode.com/2013/12/bootstrap-dropdown-button-select-box-control.html

The link above is a tutorial.

- I need help understanding what the JS in this tutorial is actually doing to the drop down.

The description below doesn't make sense to me. 
"When an item is selected, this code will change the button label and hide the menu. Now we have a select box, however, the styling on Dropdown Button does not match the styling on other form controls. When the text in the button is too short, the button shrinks to fit. When that text is too long, the button expands outside the bounds of its parent:"

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer related to button shrink and expand which you had mentioned above.

The select box width varies according to the text content, since its an inline element, you can set `min-width` to overcome it.

```
span.listname{min-width:200px;display:inline-block}
```

Answer (score -1):

just try it me be it's help...

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MansukhKhandhar/dhuybseL/)**

```
<div id="select-option" class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class='listname'>Select your option </span><span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

$(function(){

  $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){

    $(".dropdown-toggle .listname").text($(this).text());
  });

});
```